# Does Kubernetes support different Docker versions in master and nodes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have 4 ubuntu-16.04 servers, one is Kubernetes master and remaining 3 are nodes. I want to setup the kubernetes cluster on 4 servers. while setting up the cluster(By using Kubeadm) process, I have installed different docker version on master server

1. On master(docker version) --- 18.06
2. On 3 nodes(docker version) ---- 17.03

Does Kubernetes support different Docker versions in master and different docker version in nodes?

Answer (score 0):

As long as they are compatible with the local kubelet in each case, yes. The version of docker doesn’t generally matter very much, you could even use different CRI plugins on different nodes if you wanted to.